# How to force `find-file` to visit the existing frame of an opened file

Tags: frames, find-file

The below function creates a new instance of the file `myfile.txt` (regardless of if `myfile.txt` is already opened or not).

How to force emacs to use the existing frame of that file (if any)?

```
(defun visit_my_file ()
(interactive)
(find-file "/path/to/myfile.txt" t))
```

Any alternative solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

It already does that. It checks both for buffers that have opened the same exact filename, and for buffers that have opened the same file but under a different name (think of cases involving symlinks, for example). If it finds a buffer with the same `buffer-filename`, then it simply selects that buffer. If it finds a buffer that has opened the same file under a different name, then it either issues a warning or, if `find-file-existing-other-name` or `find-file-visit-truename` are non–nil, then it selects the existing buffer instead of creating a new one.